# In android can multiple receiver be called on BOOT COMPLETED?

Tags: android

I have in my manifest 2 recievers on BOOT COMPLETED. one is for location and the other is a generic one which wakes up my service activity . But I noticed when the boot is completed it is not called.

I added     //if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {} but it did not help

In manifest I have it as follows:

```
     <receiver android:name=".receiver.MyBootUpReceiver" >
             <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".helper.MyLocationReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and My recievers are as follows:

```
       public class MyBootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

           Context ctx;


       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
               Log.d(TAG,"Receiver called..");
    }
   }
```

Comment: Have you run an activity in your app yet? Until then, none of your manifest-registered receivers will work. Beyond that, there really is no reason to have two `BroadcastReceiver` instances for the same event -- just use one and have it perform both pieces of work.

Answer (score 0):

one BroadcaseReceiver is enough, you don't need two separate receivers for same event

add android:enabled="true" to your receiver in manifest file

```
   <receiver
        android:name="DeviceBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```